Parsing sites and saving found links
there are all kinds of links to sites where you need to collect links from advertising banners.
I have reread many different topics and tried many different ways, at this stage, according to many tips, I reached selenium, taking into account various attempts and errors, I threw such code using WebDriverWait and TimeoutException, and still I cannot get the desired result.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

user_agent = ‘Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3’

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://yandex.com/')

try:
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/a')))
print(element.text)
except TimeoutException:
print(“Time is over!”)

the code outputs any text and title according to the specified XPATH, but the link from the advertising banner to none.
if I understand correctly, then the problem may be that with each new opening of the browser and the page, and indeed during the presence on the page, the advertising banners are constantly updated, and the XPATH changes accordingly, the code cannot catch the XPATH that I copied in the page code on the page, because either it is already it does not exist at all, or because at the moment the advertising banner is different and, accordingly, a different XPATH. Maybe someone has faced such tasks or in principle knows how to deal with it? Maybe I'm using selenium for nothing and there is some other way...I need to collect links from banner ads on different sites...Help...

What result are you expecting? It's not clear

avoid using path based locators... at least entirely path-based.  Also be aware that many advertising links are inside of iframes.  You'd need to target per-advertiser (or network) and possibly use a partial path-based xpath.  If the ad(s) are inside of frames you'll need to swtich the driver to that frame first.  Use an explicit wait with expected condition of frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt.

It'd be helpful if you include an example of markup you are dealing with here.  Right-click in the browser, choose "Inspect", and copy/paste the markup into your post.  Then someone can make an example of how'd you go about this.
